# I am facing this issue ] typeerror undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactnative camera.default.constants') site:stackoverflow.com

Tags: react-native

there is an issue typeerror undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactnative camera.default.constants') site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: I am using this [Link]( https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/RNCamera.md)

Comment: Have you performed the installation steps from that link of RNCamera and then try to run?

Comment: no RCTCamera install

Comment: okay. then you need to install RNCamera by this two command **npm install react-native-camera --save** , **react-native link react-native-camera** and then try to run.

Comment: but error is still same

Comment: First, uninstall RCTC camera and fire above both commands then run the app.and if still issue exists fire this command **npm install --save react-native-camera@git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera.git** and import it like this {import { RNCamera, FaceDetector } from 'react-native-camera';} as it mentioned here (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera)

Comment: how to uninstall this

Answer (score -1):

I am using react native image picker and its working fine .The RNCamera and these type of library is too old and it will crash your app